# Java 8 List of list of list of Objects flatmap fetch the inner most list

Tags: java-8, flatmap

I am not so familiar with Java 8 (still learning) and looking to see if I could find something equivalent of the below code using flatMap.

I use lombok @Builder (you can ignore that part)

Few checks that we might need - Lists could be empty

A rough sketch of my objects - 
class Scratch {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object2> object2List = new ArrayList<>();
    object2List.add(Object2.builder().needThisList(Arrays.asList("good" , "bad")).build());
    object2List.add(Object2.builder().needThisList(Arrays.asList("worse" , "awesome")).build());

    List<Object2> object2List_2 = new ArrayList<>();
    object2List_2.add(Object2.builder().needThisList(Arrays.asList("good1" , "bad1")).build());
    object2List_2.add(Object2.builder().needThisList(Arrays.asList("worse1" , "awesome1")).build());

    List<Object1> object1List = new ArrayList<>();
    object1List.add(Object1.builder().object2List(object2List).build());
    object1List.add(Object1.builder().object2List(object2List_2).build());

    //Please get me final list of all the Strings


   }
}

@Builder
class Object1 {
    List<Object2> object2List;
}

@Builder
class Object2 {
    List<String> needThisList;
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the question. Use flatMap. Have you tried using it? What is the concrete problem you faced?

Comment: Well I am getting confused on the correct use of it :(
List<String> finalList = object1List.stream()
            .flatMap()
            .map()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: I am getting a bit confused with the correct use of it. 
I would have to again do a stream inside the map function?

Comment: List<String> finalList = object1List.stream()
            .map(o -> o.getObject2List().stream().map(Object2::getNeedThisList).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: The documentation has examples: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-. Stream.flatMap() returns another Stream. You can once again use flatMap on that stream.

Comment: You may also have an error in your code.  The line after initializing `List<Object2> object2List_2 = new ArrayList<>();`, do you mean to change `object2List.add(` to `object2List_2.add(`

Comment: Don't use map(). use flatMap().

Comment: List<String> finalList = object1List.stream()
            .flatMap(Object1::getObject2List)
            .flatMap(Object2::getNeedThisList)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @Cuga - You are right. Let me edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it can work without Lombock.

```
public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> object2List = new ArrayList<>();
        object2List.add(List.of("good", "bad"));
        object2List.add(List.of("worse", "awesome"));

        List<List<String>> object2List_2 = new ArrayList<>();
        object2List_2.add(Arrays.asList("good1", "bad1"));
        object2List_2.add(Arrays.asList("worse1", "awesome1"));

        List<List<List<String>>> object1List = new ArrayList<>();
        object1List.add(object2List);
        object1List.add(object2List_2);

        // Please get me final list of all the Strings

        System.out.println(object1List.stream().flatMap((outer) -> outer.stream()).flatMap((mid) -> mid.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
[good, bad, worse, awesome, good1, bad1, worse1, awesome1]
```

**Edit**

Re-reading the original post, if you want to retain the original lists (i.e., end up with a list of 4 lists) then you can do this:

```
System.out.println(object1List.stream().flatMap((outer) -> outer.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Which would print out:

```
[[good, bad], [worse, awesome], [good1, bad1], [worse1, awesome1]]
```

Comment: `List.of` is Java 9, but if it is available, there is no reason to mix it with manual list construction, i.e. you can simply use `List<List<String>> object2List = List.of(List.of("good", "bad")), List.of("worse", "awesome")), object2List_2 = List.of(List.of("good1", "bad1"), List.of("worse1", "awesome1")); List<List<List<String>>> object1List = List.of(object2List, object2List_2);`